# Example projects for jBPM integration with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jbpm

Could anybody suggest me some example application of `jBPM,` that uses `Spring` and `Hibernate?`

I am new to `jBPM` and need to get some reference application about it.

Comment: isnt it answer to your question? As for today you asked 32 question and have accepted only 8 answer - 25%

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the sample application: [A sample application, intended to provide a foundation for developers who need to build applications using jBPM 5, Spring, and Hibernate](https://github.com/Nijhazer/jbpm-spring-quickstart)

Aslo this one can be interesting for you: [JBPM-using-Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Maven](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBPM-using-Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Maven?_sscc=t)

Comment: None of the above-listed links have any usable sample projects.